# Updating blob shows PL/SQL success but no content change

Tags: oracle, plsql, blob

Attempting to update pictures in a blob column for multiple rows, I receive successful messages with no error and yet changes have not been rendered. I restarted Oracle service and machine and still nothing propagated. Yes, as shown I am committing and I have tried only one blob to no avail.

- Is it the temporary *dest_lob* object? The *readonly* type? Do I have to release the temp blob?
- Is it the appropriate schema not set? I am calling it with schema user.
- Do previous blob content have to be `NULL`? The Hamlet.jpg attempt (ID = 101) maintains `NULL` in *Picture* blob column.
- Is it a caching issue with Oracle? Do I have to refresh something like the tablespace file?
- Is it the multiple `BEGIN` ... `END` calls?

**Table**

```
 SQL > desc Characters;
 Name                  Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
 ID                    NOT NULL NUMBER(5)
 CHARACTER                      VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
 DESCRIPTION                    VARCHAR2(1000 CHAR)
 SOURCE                         VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
 QUOTE                          VARCHAR2(1500 CHAR)
 PICTURE                        BLOB
 LINKIMAGE                      VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
```

**PL-SQL**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY MY_DIR AS '/path/to/pictures';
DECLARE
  src_bfile BFILE := BFILENAME('MY_DIR', 'HenryCorwin.jpg');
  dest_blob BLOB;
BEGIN
  SELECT PICTURE into dest_blob FROM CHARACTERS WHERE ID = 44;
  DBMS_LOB.OPEN(src_bfile, DBMS_LOB.LOB_READONLY);
  DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY( dest_blob, TRUE);
  DBMS_LOB.LoadFromFile( DEST_LOB => dest_blob,
                         SRC_LOB  => src_bfile,
                         AMOUNT   => DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(src_bfile) );
  DBMS_LOB.CLOSE(src_bfile);
  COMMIT;
END;
/
DECLARE
  src_bfile BFILE := BFILENAME('MY_DIR', 'Hamlet.jpg');
  dest_blob BLOB;
BEGIN
  SELECT PICTURE into dest_blob FROM CHARACTERS WHERE ID = 101;
  DBMS_LOB.OPEN(src_bfile, DBMS_LOB.LOB_READONLY);
  DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY( dest_blob, TRUE);
  DBMS_LOB.LoadFromFile( DEST_LOB => dest_blob,
                         SRC_LOB  => src_bfile,
                         AMOUNT   => DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(src_bfile) );
  DBMS_LOB.CLOSE(src_bfile);
  COMMIT;
END;
/
DECLARE
  src_bfile BFILE := BFILENAME('MY_DIR', 'CGreen.jpg');
  dest_blob BLOB;
BEGIN
  SELECT PICTURE into dest_blob FROM  CHARACTERS WHERE ID = 15;
  DBMS_LOB.OPEN(src_bfile, DBMS_LOB.LOB_READONLY);
  DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY( dest_blob, TRUE);
  DBMS_LOB.LoadFromFile( DEST_LOB => dest_blob,
                         SRC_LOB  => src_bfile,
                         AMOUNT   => DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(src_bfile) );
  DBMS_LOB.CLOSE(src_bfile);
  COMMIT;
END;
/
DECLARE
  src_bfile BFILE := BFILENAME('MY_DIR', 'SevenOfNine.jpg');
  dest_blob BLOB;
BEGIN
  SELECT PICTURE into dest_blob FROM CHARACTERS WHERE ID = 82;
  DBMS_LOB.OPEN(src_bfile, DBMS_LOB.LOB_READONLY);
  DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY( dest_blob, TRUE);
  DBMS_LOB.LoadFromFile( DEST_LOB => dest_blob,
                         SRC_LOB  => src_bfile,
                         AMOUNT   => DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(src_bfile) );
  DBMS_LOB.CLOSE(src_bfile);
  COMMIT;
END;
/
```

**sqlplus command line call** *(of above script)*

```
SQL> @/path/to/script.sql
```

**Console Output**

```
Directory created.


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

**SQL** Blob data check

```
SELECT ID FROM Characters
WHERE DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(Picture) = 0 OR 
      DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(Picture) IS NULL;
```

**Output**

```
    ID
----------
    15
    44
    82
   101
```

**Environment**

- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, 64-bit
- Intel Celeron, 4-processor, 64-GB HD, 2-GB RAM
- Oracle 11g Express:

  ```
  SQL > select * from v$version

  Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
  PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
  CORE    11.2.0.2.0  Production
  TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
  NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
  ```

Comment: Try `INSERT INTO Characters ( ID, Picture ) VALUES ( 44, EMPTY_BLOB() );` and then use your anonymous PL/SQL block. [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/37bccc/2)

Comment: @MTO I appreciate the suggestion. However, I do not want to append new rows but update existing. Your example works from an empty table. Can we set it up for `UPDATE`? Or maybe I have to update *Picture* with `EMPTY_BLOB` entity with `writeappend`?

Comment: what you get when you take `DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH (src_bfile)` into a `variable` and the pass the variable. Can you try once ?

Comment: @XING - I tried that to no avail: `dest_length:= DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH (src_bfile) ... AMOUNT => dest_length`.

Comment: What you are doing is absolutely correct. You need to see if issue exists somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help from this other forum [thread](https://www.club-oracle.com/threads/update-blob.7726/), I found my issue. Instead of using the following LOB methods:

```
DBMS_LOB.OPEN(src_bfile, DBMS_LOB.LOB_READONLY);
```

Simply replace with the FILE version and remove the `CREATETEMPORARY()`:

```
DBMS_LOB.FILEOPEN(src_bfile, DBMS_LOB.FILE_READONLY);
```

And in hindsight this makes somewhat sense since I am reading form a file object, *src_bfile*, and not an actual blob object.

With the following updated PL/SQL routine, blob columns successfully render.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY MY_DIR AS '/path/to/pictures';
DECLARE
  src_bfile BFILE := BFILENAME('MY_DIR', 'HenryCorwin.jpg');
  dest_blob BLOB;
BEGIN
  SELECT PICTURE into dest_blob FROM CHARACTERS WHERE ID = 44 FOR UPDATE;
  DBMS_LOB.FILEOPEN(src_bfile, DBMS_LOB.FILE_READONLY);
  DBMS_LOB.LoadFromFile( DEST_LOB => dest_blob,
                         SRC_LOB  => src_bfile,
                         AMOUNT   => DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(src_bfile) );
  DBMS_LOB.FILECLOSE(src_bfile);
  COMMIT;
END;
/
DECLARE
  src_bfile BFILE := BFILENAME('MY_DIR', 'CGreen.jpg');
  dest_blob BLOB;
BEGIN
  SELECT PICTURE into dest_blob FROM  CHARACTERS WHERE ID = 15 FOR UPDATE;
  DBMS_LOB.FILEOPEN(src_bfile, DBMS_LOB.FILE_READONLY);
  DBMS_LOB.LoadFromFile( DEST_LOB => dest_blob,
                         SRC_LOB  => src_bfile,
                         AMOUNT   => DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(src_bfile) );
  DBMS_LOB.FILECLOSE(src_bfile);
  COMMIT;
END;
/
DECLARE
  src_bfile BFILE := BFILENAME('MY_DIR', 'SevenOfNine.jpg');
  dest_blob BLOB;
BEGIN
  SELECT PICTURE into dest_blob FROM CHARACTERS WHERE ID = 82 FOR UPDATE;
  DBMS_LOB.FILEOPEN(src_bfile, DBMS_LOB.FILE_READONLY);
  DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY( dest_blob, TRUE);
  DBMS_LOB.LoadFromFile( DEST_LOB => dest_blob,
                         SRC_LOB  => src_bfile,
                         AMOUNT   => DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(src_bfile) );
  DBMS_LOB.FILECLOSE(src_bfile);
  COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Also, if blob column is `NULL` like my *Hamlet.jpg* attempt the above procedure will fail with

> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: invalid LOB locator
>   specified:
>
> ORA-22275 ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_LOB", line 928 ORA-06512:
>   at line 7

To resolve, update with `EMPTY_BLOB()` prior to updating the blob with the intended object.

```
UPDATE CHARACTERS SET Picture = EMPTY_BLOB() WHERE ID = 101;
DECLARE
  src_bfile BFILE := BFILENAME('MY_DIR', 'Hamlet.jpg');
  dest_blob BLOB;
BEGIN
  SELECT PICTURE into dest_blob FROM CHARACTERS WHERE ID = 101 FOR UPDATE;
  DBMS_LOB.FILEOPEN(src_bfile, DBMS_LOB.FILE_READONLY);
  DBMS_LOB.LoadFromFile( DEST_LOB => dest_blob,
                         SRC_LOB  => src_bfile,
                         AMOUNT   => DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(src_bfile) );
  DBMS_LOB.FILECLOSE(src_bfile);
  COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Successful messages render and final query returns a sight to sore eyes:

```
SQL > SELECT ID FROM Characters WHERE DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(Picture) = 0 OR DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(Picture) IS NULL;

no rows selected

SQL > SQL> SELECT DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(Picture) FROM Characters WHERE ID IN (15, 44, 82, 101);

DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(PICTURE)
---------------------------
                     365256
                     412300
                     381586
                     404241
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest you do an `dbms_lob.erase`, which seems to be necessary:

```
SELECT PICTURE INTO dest_blob FROM CHARACTERS WHERE ID = 15
   FOR UPDATE;
dest_length := DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(dest_blob);
IF dest_length <> 0 THEN
  DBMS_LOB.ERASE(dest_blob,dest_length,1);
END IF;

-- then do as you wrote:
DBMS_LOB.OPEN(src_bfile, DBMS_LOB.LOB_READONLY);
DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY( dest_blob, TRUE);
DBMS_LOB.LoadFromFile( DEST_LOB => dest_blob,
                       SRC_LOB  => src_bfile,
                       AMOUNT   => DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(src_bfile) );
DBMS_LOB.CLOSE(src_bfile);
COMMIT;
```

Hope this helps (stolen from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35482890/ora-22288-file-or-lob-operation-fileopen-failed-filename-directory-name-is-in))

Comment: Unfortunately, same exact output with the strange *success* messages with no error but no update!